# How to change the font size of line numbers using the Minted Latex Package

Tags: latex

I tried redefining the \FancyVerbLine to have a \large, but that didn't help. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should do the trick. How *exactly* does your `\FancyVerbLine` look like? Notice that it’s not enough to put the formatting in – you also need to include the counter command:

```
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\large\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}
```

This should work.